# How to deploy gradle spring boot java war application into app engine standard (not flex env)

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine

I have a project and I don't want to use AppEngine flex as they are expensive. So I converted my project to standard by converting spring boot application from `jar` to `war`

When I try to deploy the project to the app engine it is picking `app.yaml` rather `appening-web.xml` and deploying as a flex project rather standard.

Did anyone face the same?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `appengine-web.xml` file is under the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` directory. Your structure should look lke this:

[image]

For more detailed information about the App Engine Standard configuration files for Java please check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuration-files). You can also check the [steps](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard) in this GitHub page on how to deploy a Spring Boot simple Hello World app in App Engine Standard.